# C++ insert vector into another vector with overwrite

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector <char> grid(10);
for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < grid.size(); temp1++) {
    grid[temp1] = 'g';
}
vector <char> ship(3);
for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < ship.size(); temp2++) {
    ship[temp2] = 's';
}

int location = 2;

void insertfunction(grid, ship, location) {
     // what function code to write?
     return grid 
}
```

Say I have two vectors: grid (length 10, 'gggggggggg') and ship ('sss'). I want to insert vector ship into vector grid and overwrite the original value based on the location I choose.
For example, if location is 2, I should get "ggsssggggg"
If location is 5, I should get "gggggsssgg"

How should I write the insertfunction for this to work?

Sorry I am new to C++

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: your `ship` has size `3` yet you iterate over till beyond it, in your second loop `temp2 < grid.size()` , that is `undefined behaviour`. Perhaps loop till 3, ship.size()?

Comment: There is no `replace` in a vector, but you can easily combine `erase` and `insert` to get that effect.

Comment: try using .at() when vectors have problems

Comment: @SamerTufail yup I meant ship.size() sorry

Comment: @Darhuuk I was thinking if there is any replace function but guess I will just use erase and insert

Comment: @WXYZ can you fix your example code above so it shows what the problem is?

Comment: erase+insert is quite inefficient, not that it matters in such a tiny vector.

Comment: @jww Why isn't the answer of SebastianRedl good enough?

Comment: @jrok - I'd like to use an STL solution that provides checked iterators. With Microsoft they are enabled in debug builds when using `-DDEBUG`. libstdc++ provides them when `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (sanity check included):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void overwriteVectorWithOffset(std::vector<char> &target, std::vector<char> const &source, size_t offset)
{
    size_t end = min(target.size(), source.size() + offset);
    size_t i = 0;

    while (offset < end)
        target[offset++] = source[i++];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <char> grid(10, 'e');
    std::vector <char> ship(3, 'f');

    overwriteVectorWithOffset(grid, ship, 2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << grid[i];

    std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: That is really smart! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

```
std::copy(ship.begin(), ship.end(), grid.begin() + offset);
```

This overwrites the elements. Be careful not to run out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) for the job. You only need to get `count` to be the minimum distance between `[ship.begin(), ship.end()]` against `[grip.begin() + location, grip.end()]`. This will ensure no out of bounds error.

In code (BTW, just assuming that location is positive, otherwise, further checks will be necessary):

```
// Sanity check
auto offset = std::min(grid.begin() + location, grid.end());

// calculating count, as described above
auto grid_distance = std::distance(offset, grid.end());
auto ship_distance = std::distance(ship.begin(), ship.end());
auto count = std::min(grid_distance, ship_distance);

std::copy_n(ship.begin(), count, offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> grid(10, 'e');
std::vector<char> ship(3, 'f');

void InsertShip(int position)
{
    if (position >= 0 && position < grid.size())
        std::transform(ship.begin(), ship.end(), grid.begin() + position, 
            [](const char& ch) { return ch; });
}

int main()
{
    InsertShip(2);

    for (const auto& ch : grid)
        std::cout << ch;

    getchar();
}
```